# How do I combine two textures?

Tags: texture-baking

I need to combine two textures of a Gun Sight while maintaining transparency.
Please ive been trying to do it for 4 hours
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of your textures has an alpha channel, you can connect it like this. In the image below, I mix a Moss Texture (with transparency) with the BaseColor of a Concrete PBR Material, using a MixRGB node, and the Moss Texture's alpha channel as a mix factor.

[image: ALphaMix]